# Label encoder save and load in training an LLM using PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I am currently working to fine-tune BERT model in transformers, using PyTorch, I have more than 30,000 labels, and I am wondering how to do the label encoding.
To start with, I am trying to micro-train the Model by using only 500 sample data -> 400 for train, 100 for validation. So, I have train_labels, and val_labels as well.

The idea is after training, I would like to do 'inference' for evaluation as well, but I keep on getting the error when doing label_encoder.inverse_transform(), saying that the number is not in my label_encoder.
`decoded_label = label_encoder.inverse_transform([predicted_label])[0]`

I did save the label encoder before training,

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import joblib

combined_data = pd.concat([train_data, val_data],ignore_index=True)
combined_labels = label_encoder.fit_transform(combined_data['expected_label'])

joblib.dump(label_encoder, "save-directory.joblib")

# Convert combined label to tensor
combined_labels = torch.tensor(combined_labels)
```

But in during training and validation, I use separate encoded labels. 'train_labels' for training,
`train_dataset = TensorDataset(train_input_ids, train_attention_masks, train_labels)`
and 'val_labels' for validating
`val_dataset = TensorDataset(val_input_ids, val_attention_masks, val_labels)`

I have tried to save the encoded train_labels

```
train_labels = label_encoder.fit_transform(train_data['expected_genre'])
joblib.dump(label_encoder, "save-directory.joblib")
```

And load it on other .py file when I am about to use it:
`label_encoder = joblib.load("save-directory.joblib")`

But when doing the inverse_transform:
`decoded_label = label_encoder.inverse_transform([predicted_label])[0]`
I get the error *ValueError: y contains previously unseen labels: 119*
As if 119 is not encoded in the train_labels but infact it's there.

My question is what are:

1. What is the right implementation for saving the label_encoder? Should it be combined first then saved?